# MySQL query from 3 tables at once

Tags: mysql

I try to get data from 3 tables at once, tables are:

- candidates
- languages
- candidates_language

Each of it represent some data about all users in my database.

As names suggest first table contains some general data like: firstname, surname, email.

```
candidates
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |   id   |     firstname    |      surname       |        email        |
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |   22   |      John        |        Doe         |    john@doe.com     |
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |   23   |      Peter       |       Miller       |    doe@john.com     |
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Second one contains just languages_id and languageName

```
languages
    ---------------------------------
    | languageID |     languageName |
    ---------------------------------
    |      1     |      English     |
    ---------------------------------
    |      2     |      German      |
    ---------------------------------
    |      3     |      Spanish     |
    ---------------------------------
```

And last one try to connect all this together:

```
    candidates_language 
   (foreign keys: candidates_id to table candidates,languageID to languages)
        -----------------------------------------------------------------
        |   id   |   candidates_id  |  languageID |        skill        |
        -----------------------------------------------------------------
        |   1    |        22        |       1     |        basic        |
        -----------------------------------------------------------------
        |   2    |        22        |       3     |        basic        |
        -----------------------------------------------------------------
        |   3    |        23        |       1     |        advance      |
        -----------------------------------------------------------------
        |   4    |        23        |       2     |        basic        |
        -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to connect results from this 3 tables for just some specific languages and make something like below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |   firstname  |    surname     |      email      | english | german |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 22 |    John      |      Doe       |  john@doe.com   |  basic  |    -   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 23 |    Peter     |     Miller     |  doe@john.com   | advance |  basic |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I try to connect get to this point with code below::

```
SELECT
    candidates.firstname,
    candidates.surname,
    candidates_language.candidates_id,
    candidates_language.skill,
    languages.languageID
FROM
    candidates,
    candidates_language,
    languages
```

Unfortunately I am just far away from actual results I want. Is there a chance someone can help me with this?

Comment: Do you want one column for *each* available language in your Languages table, or do you want columns only for specific languages?

Comment: Hi  RavB,
I need just columns for specific languages.btw edited my question base on your note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If number of languages is *predefined*, then you can use *conditional aggregates* to get desired result set:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN cl.languageID = 1 THEN cl.skill ELSE '-' END) AS 'English',
       MAX(CASE WHEN cl.languageID = 2 THEN cl.skill ELSE '-' END) AS 'German',
       MAX(CASE WHEN cl.languageID = 3 THEN cl.skill ELSE '-' END) AS 'Spanish'
FROM candidates AS c
LEFT JOIN candidates_language AS cl ON c.id = cl.candidates_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.firstname, c.surname, c.email
```

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b782/3)

Otherwise you have to employ [dynamic sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: This looks pretty awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

As the languages are not fixed, you can't add in select as you want.

The other alternative is for each language you will get one record.

```
    select candidates.id, candidates.firstname, candidates.surname, candidates.email, languages.languageName, candidates_language.skill from candidates_language inner join candidates.id on candidates_language.candidates_id inner join languages.id on candidates.languageID
```

Answer (score -1):

Inner joins should work for this.

You can do the following:

```
SELECT 
  c.firstname,
  c.surname,
  cl.candidates_id,
  cl.skill,
  l.languageID
FROM candidates c
INNER JOIN candidates_language cl
    on c.id = cl.candidates_id
INNER JOIN languages l
    on l.languageID = cl.languageID
```

Comment: Hi patmcc, 
thanks for your comment, unfortunately this make duplicity of Users :)